# Hide website navigation from the home page

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I created a site in wordpress and I want to hide the menu from this page

http://www.dawaf.co.uk/es/

but keep it visible on all of the other pages once you click on the logo in the top left to take you through to the site

http://www.dawaf.co.uk/es/portraits

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    border: 0;
    font-family: BebasRegular;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

body {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 0px;
}

h1.entry-title {
    display: none;
}

#page.hfeed {
    margin: 0px;
}

/*Header
------------------------------------------------------------ */
#branding {
    border: 0px;
}

#branding #searchform {
    display: none;
}

.site-title {
    width: 300px;
    height: 132px;
}

/*Nav
------------------------------------------------------------ */
#access {
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    width: 140px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#access a {
    color: #8E8E8E;
    padding: 0px;
    line-height: 2.2;
}

#access li {
    font-size: 11px;
}

#access li:hover > a, #access a:focus {
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

#access .current-menu-item > a, #access .current-menu-ancestor > a, #access .current_page_item > a, #access .current_page_ancestor > a {
    font-weight: normal;
}

/*Photospace
------------------------------------------------------------ */
.photospace {
    margin: 0px !important;
    top: -236px;
    left: 175px;
}

.nav-controls {
    font-size: 11px;
}

.ss-controls {
    font-size: 11px;
}

.photospace .gal_content a:hover{
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

/*Super Sized Splash Page
------------------------------------------------------------ */
#supersized {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -999;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#page.hfeed {
    background: transparent;
}

.widget_search form {
    display: none;
}

form#searchform {
    display: none;
}

/*Footer
------------------------------------------------------------ */
#colophon {
    display: none;
}

#post-0 .entry-content {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: What's being asked here? If I click on the logo I get a "Forbidden" error on the folder /child/videos; but the menu seems to work fine. It *should* be there. Anyway, I'd guess that to hide a menu/widget on a particular page will need some PHP coding rather than CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll notice that your main page has a class of `home` which is unique to that section. This makes it real simple to do something like:

```
.home nav{
    display:none;
}
```

or if you need something more specific:

```
.home nav#access{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd edit the theme and check [`is_home()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) to hide the menu.

```
if( !is_home() )
{
    # Show your menu on pages that are not the home page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could hide it from the home page by doing the following css

```
.home #access {
    display: none;
    }
```

It will still appear on all of your other pages once you enter via the logo.